# How to use angularjs component with angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

[Angular material](https://material.angular.io/) is yet in development and does not has all component ready, am currently using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) for web development and wonder how can I use components from [angularjs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) to it.

Thanks

Update: getting the error as below while using autocoplete

````
```


 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mdAutocomplete' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("red box</h1>
  <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
    <input mdInput placeholder="State" [ERROR ->][mdAutocomplete]="reactiveAuto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
  </md-input-container>

"): PracticeComponent@4:39
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "mdAutocomplete" ("
  </md-input-container>

  <div md-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#reactiveAuto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of reactiv"): PracticeComponent@7:23
Can't bind to 'displayWith' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
  </md-input-container>

  <div md-autocomplete #reactiveAuto="mdAutocomplete" [ERROR ->][displayWith]="displayFn">
    <md-option *ngFor="let state of reactiveStates | async" [value]="state"): PracticeComponent@7:54 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
```
````

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, they aren't compatible. No more scope, "zones" instead of digests, it's just a different animal. I had some AngularJS code I wanted to reuse and I tried a couple of ways to wrap it, even tried running AngularJS and Angular2 side by side just to see if I could do it. In the end it was just easier to rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I want to use something similar to md-autocomplete, is there any read to eat material available ?

Comment: @nishantpathak The material 2 already has autocomplete component.

Comment: I searched for it and found it pretty readily. Go to material 2 for that one. However, I'd add, that if you want to restructure a component from Angular JS to Angular2, the task is not as ominous as it sounds. The component definitions etc. are a pretty robotic process to migrate, I did it to a number of my old Angular directives (which were really always just components), moved around the var inits and so on to ngOnInit (fortunately I never loaded up the scope), tweaked a few times, and it all just sort of worked. I was actually surprised, I thought it would be a LOT more difficult.

Comment: And for the record, I thought this was a good question, so I evened out the downvote.

Comment: @developer033 can you please refer me to that. I tried to code and getting error.

Comment: Got it, I can see it in pre release @developer033. https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/2.0.0-beta.2 Thanks for your input.